# Incrementing and showing number on click in Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

This is the code:

```py
def money():
    money += 1
t.write('Money: ' + str(money))
player.onclick(money, 1)
```

What shows up on turtle is:

```
Money: <function money at 0x00000249BA69B010>
```

I tried changing format and string but it just won't show anything different

I'm looking for:

```
Money: 0
```

Comment: You should post a [mre]. That said, you are using the same symbol 'money' for your global variable and function.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues here. For starters, you can't use a variable `money` to represent two things at once. There should be separate variable names for the function that runs on click and the integer that represents how much money the player has. Since functions are usually actions, let's call it `add_money`, and call the integer `money`.

Next, to track the money across multiple clicks, `money` needs to be outside of the callback function. To be able to increment a variable from an enclosing scope, we need the `global` or `nonlocal` keywords. If we don't use an outer function closure, `global` is the only choice here.

`t.write` is only called once outside of the callback, so it won't re-write after each click, unless there's some additional looping code you haven't shown. We should call that in the loop so we can rerender the current money amount.

Having made the above changes, you'll see turtle is a bit fussy about rendering, labels and clicking. If we use `t.write` directly, the label will be placed on top of the turtle, making it hard to click again. There'll also be a blink when the label draws. To solve these issues, I added `tracer(0)` to disable rendering, `update()` to render a frame, and pen up/down and movement to position the label away from the turtle so it doesn't interfere with the click hitbox.

`player.clear()` is used to clear the label.

Lastly, turtles are small by default, so I made the turtle larger to give the user a large hitbox for the click.

You're welcome to change or remove any of these peripheral UX decisions if they're not relevant to your app, but I felt they were necessary to ensure you could interact with this example easily.

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


def show_money():
    player.clear()
    player.forward(20)
    player.pendown()
    player.write(f"Money: {money}", font=("monospace", 16))
    player.penup()
    player.backward(20)


def add_money(x, y):
    global money
    money += 1
    show_money()
    Screen().update()


money = 0
Screen().tracer(0)
player = Turtle()
player.shape("circle")
player.penup()
player.turtlesize(1.2, 1.2)
player.onclick(add_money)
show_money()
Screen().update()
Screen().mainloop()
```